# tail -f logfile is not showing the newly added entries

Tags: linux, file, tail

I have a log file contents of `log.file` are

```
123
123
321
312
123
412
151
```

I have done `tail -f log.file`. In other session, I have opened the same log file and appended more values. my assumption is that `tail -f log.file` should show the newly appended values but its not showing.

Comment: Please answer, and put -1

Comment: Have you saved the file in other session?

Comment: yes, i did. i have notice one more behavior like echo  'aaaa ' >>  logfile is reflecting the tail -f logfile output but in vi editor i have written (:w) its not reflecting in the tail -f logfile

Comment: Could be the swap file? Have you tried exiting? I have found something more interesting.  Saving the file make my tail to exit with return status as "0" i.e. success

Comment: @user60679: does `tail -F log.file` work?

Comment: How exactly did you "opened the same log file and appended"?

Comment: yes, it does work. i am appended like opening the file in vi and adding more entries and saving it. @AaronDigulla

Answer (score 4):

That depends on how you open the file and append. You have to make sure the change happens "in place"

This will work:

```
echo >> logfile
```

This won't:

```
vi logfile
```

Why not? `vi` is equivalent to:

```
mv logfile logfile~
echo >> logfile
```

After this sequence of commands, `tail -f` will follow `logfile~`; it won't see the newly created file.

This happens because `tail` doesn't follow the name; it follows the file descriptor which doesn't change when the name changes. This approach allows Unix all kinds of neat tricks (like `echo` appending to the file while `tail` has it open).

`tail -F` would work since it notices that the file was renamed.

Comment: @Nishant: How do you modify the file? If you modify in place, it works. But you may have a special version of `tail`; I'm talking about GNU Tail from the package coreutils.

Comment: i opened the file using vi in one putty session and modified it, while tail -f file.txt was run in another session.

Comment: @Nishant: Interesting. I wouldn't expect that to work. `vi` makes a working copy of the file (and often a backup). It depends a bit on how you configure it. Also, `vi` might in fact be `vim`.